# combine normal query and prepared query in php mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I have used the following php mysqli database class
[PHP MYSqli class](https://github.com/ajillion/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class)

In the below cases how can I use prepared statement

```
$qry =  " SELECT * FROM Master WHERE CustomerID = $customer_id ";
    $qry.= (!empty($type)) ? " and Type=? " : "";
    $qry.= (!empty($status)) ? " and Status=$status " : "";
    $qry.= (!empty($inline)) ? " and $inline " : "";
    $qry.= " ORDER BY JobID DESC ";
    $start =  !(empty($limit)) ? ($list_limit[$limit] * $page) : 0;
    $end =  !(empty($limit)) ? $list_limit[$limit]   : 20;
    $qry.= " LIMIT $start,$end ";
    //echo $qry;
    return $results = $db->rawQuery($qry,array($type));
```

While performing the above operation getting error as

```
Warning: mysqli_stmt::bind_param(): Number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement in /var/www/proj/lib/mydb.php on line 64
```

Comment: When i get this error, I eventually end up finding out that the number of columns i am trying to update are more or less than the number of parameters i am passing to the query

Comment: which line is line 64?

Comment: BTW, ajillion's class is unusable and insecure

Comment: @OptimusPrime check the [line](https://github.com/ajillion/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class/blob/master/MysqliDb.php#L131)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that number of variables doesn't match number of parameters in prepared statement. They must match.

Also note that you shouldn't combine "normal" and prepared query. All your queries have to be prepared only.

Comment: but is such condition I need to use multiple if statements right?

Comment: Well, if you have to - then use

Comment: Any other way of doing such thing?